# c# Async function - try to sum values in foreach loop

Tags: c#, asynchronous

i have a problem with CalcTime function, i try to sum all values from events in async way but i
get a wrong value, i want to gets 60 seconds but i gets different value every run:

```
async Task main()
{
    // do stuff
    Task timeTask = class1.CalcTime();
    await Task.WhenAll(timeTask);

}

public class class1 {
    // In events lists have 6 events and each event is 10 seconds
    public async Task CalcTime()
    {
        double actTime  = 0;
        List<Task<double>> list = new List<Task<double>>();
        foreach (Event event in events)
        {
            list.Add(Task.Run(() => actTime += ReturnTime(event)));
        }    

            await Task.WhenAll(list);
        
            // actTime gets a different value in each run, why?
    }

    public double ReturnTime(Event event)
    {
       return event.Time;
    }
```

}

why it's happen? and how to fix it?

and more question,
if i use Task.WhenAll inside function and after i call this function in main function
i need to set Task.WhenAll also in main to this specific function?
or is it enough to call it just in function?

and if i using await word with Task.WhenAll so the function is stop until all the job done
or Task.WhenAll waiting that all jobs done and at the same time the thread is available for another job
and can continue work in main function?

Thanks!

Comment: You're not updating `actTime` in a thread-safe way: there's no locking here, so two threads might read `actTime` at the same time, both add their own value to it, then the first thread writes back to it, then the second thread writes back, overwriting the write just done by the first thread! It would be better to return a time from each `Task` *without* updating a shared variable, and then sum them once all of the tasks have completed

Answer (score 3):

As canton7 said [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64661928/c-sharp-async-function-try-to-sum-values-in-foreach-loop#comment114331448_64661928), you can avoid all thread-safety traps by collecting the result of each `Task<double>`, and summing the partial results after all tasks have completed. This way the tasks will not step on each other toes, by trying to update a shared variable in an unsynchronized fashion.

```
var tasks = new List<Task<double>>();
foreach (var event in events)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => ReturnTime(event)));
}    
double[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
double actTime = results.Sum();
```

Comment: Or you could use `actTime += await Task.Run(() => ReturnTime(event))`, because you'll be awaiting those tasks anyway

Comment: @RamenAmaya That does mean waking up the original thread N times through, rather than once.

Comment: @canton7 Won't the original thread be blocked by any of those awaits anyway? How can you be sure the continuation will happen on the same thread ? To me it seems that this does matter little. In both ways,`Task.Run` is used to indicate that we want to launch our process on a new thread (ThreadPool will manage all this on its own), and it behaves kinda the same, or I misunderstood you? (Please don't hesitate to correct me)

Comment: @RamenAmaya It's simply the number of awaits. Theodor's code has 1, yours has N. In your case, *some* thread (it may or may not be the original thread, depending on whether it has a SynchronizationContext installed on it) needs to wake up once for each task being awaited, to add a value to `actTime`.

Comment: @RamenAmaya by creating and awaiting each task inside the loop, the tasks will be executed sequentially. The OP probably wants to execute them in parallel.

Comment: I understand, need to review my async lessons I guess, thanks @canton7 for answering